# Mathjax: Put text next to code

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I recently started using Mathjax however, I'm struggling to figure out how to put text next to functions since I don't see any CSS files for them.

I'm currently using TeX to Jax format with the $$text$$ format (not inline, as seen here).
[image: current set up]

Code for the above image:

```
 Solve:
 $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2+x}{3x}$$ 
 $$=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x(x+1)}{3x}$$ 
 $$=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x+1}{3}$$ 
 $$=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{3}$$
```

At its current state, whenever I put text next to the TeX code, it just goes to the next line. Is there any way to edit it so that I am able to put normal text like this:

[image: what I want]

Code that I want for the above image:

```
 Solve:
 $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2+x}{3x}$$ text
 $$=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x(x+1)}{3x}$$ 
 $$=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x+1}{3}$$ 
 $$=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{3}$$
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2+x}{3x}
  &=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x(x+1)}{3x}  &&\text{Text}\\[5px]
  &=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x+1}{3}      &&\text{More text}\\[5px]
  &=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{3}        &&\text{Last text}
\end{align}
```

which is the usual way to accomplish such tasks.

Comment: I'm wondering if the OP simply asks about inline mode vs display mode.

Comment: I hadn't considered that, but from the layout, I suspect that the OP really is after an alignment.

Comment: I was looking more for raw HTML rather than using LaTeX.